# Spotipy User Playlist Remove Tracks Issue

Tags: python, json, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to use the Spotipy method to delete repeat occurrences of a track (so delete duplicates). But the function doesn't seem to work; the Spotify API call is returning an error that there is no authorization token. 

Spotify API Return Error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

Python's Errors:

```
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\PythonProjects\PlaylistTransfer\Spotify.py", line 87, in remove_all_duplicate_tracks
    sp.user_playlist_remove_specific_occurrences_of_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks)
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\PythonProjects\PlaylistTransfer\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 539, in user_playlist_remove_specific_occurrences_of_tracks
    payload=payload)
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\PythonProjects\PlaylistTransfer\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 183, in _delete
    return self._internal_call('DELETE', url, payload, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dylan\Documents\PythonProjects\PlaylistTransfer\venv\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 124, in _internal_call
    headers=r.headers)
spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/___________________________/tracks:
 Could not remove tracks, please check parameters.
```

Here is my code:

```python
def remove_all_duplicate_tracks(playlist_id, token):
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(token)
    username = get_username(token)
    existing_tracks = get_track_uris_for_playlist(playlist_id, token)
    duplicate_counter = Counter(existing_tracks)
    tracks = []
    for uri, count in duplicate_counter.items():
        count = count-1
        if count > 0:
            # hard coded position as 1 for testing...
            positions = [1]
            #positions = [x for x in range(1, count+1)]
            track_dict = {"uri": uri, "positions": positions}
            tracks.append(track_dict)
    sp.user_playlist_remove_specific_occurrences_of_tracks(username, playlist_id, tracks)
```

This is what "tracks" contains:

`[{'uri': '6jq6rcOikCZAmjliAgAmfT', 'positions': [1]}, {'uri': '3tSmXSxaAnU1EPGKa6NytH', 'positions': [1]}, {'uri': '7jeI6EdY0elPSNz80mAKS8', 'positions': [1]}]`

I tested the other methods `get_username()` and `get_track_uris_for_playlist` and they return what you'd expect and are working.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer comes quite late, it is needed because 1) the question is not solved and 2) I believe that it will be helpful to people with a similar problem.

First of all, you should restrict your question to the specific problem, which is the authorization error produced by calling the `sp.user_playlist_remove_specific_occurrences_of_tracks()` function. This would make the problem more clear. (In the way it is put, one has to dig up the code to find the "hot" spot! Also the details about the tracks just add to the confusion.)

So, I will limit my answer to just the problem and suggest using the following code as a basis:

```
# Data
username = (your username)
playlist_id = (playlist id)  # The ID of the playlist containing the tracks to be deleted
track_ids = [(track_id), (track_id), ...]  # List of track IDs to delete

# Authorization process
scope = "playlist-read-private"
token = spotipy.util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope=scope)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

# Call the track deletion function
sp.user_playlist_remove_all_occurrences_of_tracks(username, playlist_id, track_ids)
```

I am using this process myself. I have **just tried** the above code with data of mine and it should also work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to change user data:

**`Could not remove tracks, please check parameters.`**

Pass a valid scope, such as:

> playlist-modify-public
>
> playlist-modify-private

More on scopes: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```